# Why have a Error when adding products to the Cart?

Tags: php, laravel, vanilo

I'm Working With Vanilo Framework but i don't understand that error

> TypeError
> PHP 8.0.19
> 9.52.7
> Vanilo\Foundation\Factories\CheckoutDataFactory::createShippingAddress(): Return value must be of type Vanilo\Contracts\Address, Konekt\AppShell\Models\Address returned

> Expand vendor frames
> 2 vendor frames
> ReflectionClass
> 0
> newInstanceArgs
> 39 vendor frames
> App
>  \ 
> Http
>  \ 
> Controllers
>  \ 
> CartController
>  
> : 24
> store
> 45 vendor frames
> public
>  / 
> index
> .php
>  
> : 52
> require_once
> 1 vendor frame
> app
>  / 
> Http
>  / 
> Controllers
>  / 
> CartController
> .php
>  
> : 24

```
use Vanilo\Product\Contracts\Product;





class CartController extends Controller

{

    //


public function index()

{

    $cartItems = CartFacade::items();

    return view('cart.show', compact('cartItems'));

}



public function store(Product $product)

{

    CartFacade::addItem($product);
```

I'm only adding products to the card, and I'm not checkout the sell at that moment

Update: I try to Update to PHP 8.2 and still have the same error, I'm putting a link to the error: https://flareapp.io/share/NPLN4Q85#F50

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is there anything unclear aboout the given error message? Also, the code you've shared doesn't call nor define `createShippingAddress`

Comment: What version of Vanilo are you using?

Answer (score -1):

I think you're using the lastest version of Vanilo (as of this time 3.1). It's requirement is to use PHP version 8.1 or higher. Kindly upgrade your PHP to 8.1 or higher.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that using a different PHP version resolves the given error message?